# What is the Henle difficulty of Bartok's opus 14 suite?

Tags: piano, practice, bartok

What Henle difficulty would Bartok's opus 14 suite be?

I want to know in order to practise more efficiently...

Comment: What's 'Henle'?

Comment: @Tim Presumably Henle Verlag, the publisher.

Comment: I fail to see, how the single-digit ranking of a single piece can evolve into a practise schedule; even if you had the ranking for all pieces this is far from being straight-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Henle typically shows you the difficulty levels on their website.

On [Henle's page for the Op. 14 Suite](https://www.henle.de/us/detail/?Title=Suite%20op.%2014_1403), under "Contents/Details" you see that they list this as Level 7 (difficult).

And if you want further clarification of their leveling system, you can find it [here](https://www.henle.de/us/about-us/levels-of-difficulty-piano/). In short, they have a nine-tiered system, with 1 listed as easiest and 9 as most difficult.